# Open files referenced in nested file structure

Tags: python, nested, structure

I have an xml file structure with a main xml referencing some other xml files (with full path), and these others reference other ones, and so on.
I have many xml files (in a simple folder structure, just a main folder and 3 subfolders) but not all of them are referenced within other xml files, so the idea is to build a list with ONLY the referenced xml files.

[image]

[EDIT]
This is a very simplified example of an xml file. main.xml is very much like this. Other files don't have the *children* tag so they are the end of the nested reference line.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <file>
   <indiv>
        <name>Name Surname</name>
        <birth> Oct 1826 </birth>
        <death> Jan 1850 </death>        
   </indiv>
   <children>
        <chname1>Name1 Surname1</chname1>
        <chcode1>F45DH3</chcode1><chdata1>C:\base\codedb\F45DH3.xml</chdata1>
        <chname2>Name2 Surname2</chname2>
        <chdata2>C:\base\namedb\name2sur2.xml</chdata2>
   </children>
 </file>
```

[/EDIT]

As there are too many files to check manually I want to use a python script to read all the files starting from my main path and build the list.
How can I do it.

This is what I have so far, but evidently these would be very long to code as I don't know how many levels of referencing I will find.
Any idea?

```
coreFile= r"C:\\base\\main.xml"
xmlList = []

with open(coreFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "C:\\base" in line:
            start = line.find('C:\\base')
            end = line.find('.xml')
            path = line[start:end + 4]

            if path not in xmlList:
                x.append(path)
                with open(path) as f2:
                    for line2 in f2:
                        if "C:\\base" in line2:
                            start = line.find('C:\\base')
                            end = line.find('.xml')
                            path = line[start:end + 4]

                            if path not in xmlList:
                                x.append(path)
                                with open(path) as f3:
                                    # ...
```

Comment: add `main.xml` sample data  to the question.

Comment: @RedBoy Done. Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to care about levels of referencing. Just go throught each file, write down every new reference you find, you are done.

Comment: @Goyo How would you do it? Bear in mind not all XML files in my folder structure are referenced within some other and therefore I don't want to read them or any references to other files within them.

Comment: If any more explanation is needed just tell me. No need to give negative points to the thread without even asking me or telling me why. If I had found it easy to solve I wouldn't ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer myself.

In case it may help someone else, it's as simple as using a function.

Remember this approach is useful when not all files in the folder structure are referenced within other files, so you need to read the main file and go on reading the referenced files in the next levels.

If what you want is to find file references within all files in a folder structure forget this. Just read each file in the folder and subfolders.

```
def xmlRefs(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for line in f:
            if "C:\\base" in line:
                start = line.find('C:\\base')
                end = line.find('.xml')
                path = line[start:end + 4]

                if path not in xmlList:
                    x.append(path)
                    xmlList.append(path)
                    print path
                    xmlRefs(path)

coreFile= r"C:\\base\\main.xml"
xmlList = []
xmlRefs(coreFile)
```